# Simple C program compiles on OS X but not Fedora 16, math.h included but not used

Tags: c, macos, gcc, fedora, autotools

All of the code can be found here https://github.com/cole-christensen/airC

It seems painfully obvious, but it doesn't work. `#include <math.h>` is there and yet M_PI isn't recognized

```
airC.c: In function ‘x_curved’:
airC.c:94:33: error: ‘M_PI’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

System Information

```
gcc version 4.6.2 20111027 (Red Hat 4.6.2-1) (GCC)
Linux fedora-oe 3.2.6-3.fc16.x86_64
```

I assume it could only have something to do with autotools.  Feel free to otherwise criticize my mess :)

**EDIT:**

<strike>Downvotes and a link to an unhelpful answer are not appreciated.</strike>

The manpage explicitly states that M_PI is defined and M_PI is actually defined in /usr/include/math.h behind an #ifdef which I do not understand.

Comment: That is an inadequate answer. /usr/include/math.h does have M_PI and the manpage for math.h says "The <math.h> header shall provide for the following constants." with M_PI following shortly after.

Comment: Could you post the ifdef? Might be of some help to find out why it isn't found.

Comment: /* Some useful constants.  */
#if defined __USE_BSD || defined __USE_XOPEN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`M_PI` is not standard C.

You have to define `_GNU_SOURCE` to enable it on Linux. OS X is derived from BSD, so the rules are probably different there.

Comment: Is there a sane way to do this in a simple multi-platform way? (preferably using autotools)

Comment: Yes, put a test for M_PI in your `configure.ac`. If it doesn't find it, try again with `_GNU_SOURCE` defined, and if that works add `-D_GNU_SOURCE` to your `CFLAGS` (or another variable of your choice).

Comment: `__GNU_SOURCE` is probably the wrong macro to look for, `M_PI` comes with POSIX so one should use the features from there. And actually you should normally not have to deal with this. `__XOPEN_SOURCE` is supposed to contain the actual POSIX version that your system implements. The compiler interface foreseen for POSIX is called `c99`, perhaps try if using that instead of `gcc` triggers the correct defininitions.

Comment: I just tried on Ubuntu: `gcc` gives `M_PI` without anything extra, `gcc -ansi` does not, neither does `gcc -std=c99`, and nor does `c99`. In all cases, defining `_GNU_SOURCE` defines `M_PI` once more.

Comment: It might be that `__XOPEN_SOURCE` is *more* correct though, I don't know.